# Sass: Variable selector name as value. (Suffix)

Tags: variables, sass, selector

How to use the suffix of a class name (selector) as value?
For example inject the width in a dynamic class name like:

Pseudo code of css or sass.

```html
<div class="column width-120"></div>
```

```css
.column.width[$width] {
  width: {$width + 'px'};
}
```

or use it for dynamic icon names.

```html
<div class="icon-home"></div>
```

```css
.icon-[$name] {
  background-image: url({$name});
}
```

For attributes it is possible with the method `attr()`. Is this also possible for a class name?

Solution for attribute:

```html
<div class="icon" name="home"></div>
```

```css
.icon {
  background-image: url(attr(name));
}
```

Comment: Use `ngClass` property for dynamic classes

Comment: I work with Angular, right. But my question has nothing to do with Angular. It's about css/sass variables in selector names. If I use ngClass I still have to use fixed (pre-defined) names. In this case all icons names must be exist in the css file. My question is about to use dynamic icon names in a sass file. ...

Comment: It's not posible what you're trying to achieve, because the idea of sass is to compile to a static css file and you don't have this kind of feature in css. The only way to have those class names working is to generate all posibles values of width and icons.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I had already suspected that. Now I use JavaScript (Angular / TypeScript) to overwrite the styles by html style declarations. ViewChild() nativeElement. ... Not sure if this is my final solution, but it works. ... It's correct, sass converts to css and css is more or less static. Less, because it's possible to use variables or dynamic values like with the `attr()` function. But this is a bit experimental. It's works mostly with strings for url and content. Perfect for my icon example. But does not work with other units like animation duration. ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).

```css
:root {
  --color: green;
}

.icon {  
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon" style="--color: red;"></div>
<div class="icon" style="--color: blue;"></div>
```

[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*#Browser_compatibility) is not perferct.